# Magento 1.9.1 getting wrong address in order

Tags: php, magento

I'm having very strange issue with Magento 1.9.1.0. I think that may be a bug.

After I've created test order I have wrong data in:

Store Emails , Order Details Address and Order Details Items.

For Example , I've made order With Customer Data:

```
Aleksandra Nowak
Street: Testowa Ulica
City: Testowe Miasto
```

I've selected the same shipping and order address.

After I continued my order I got 1 email from my shop with complete wrong address data and sometimes wrong item prizes. In order details i have the same wrong address.

What i did to solve the issue:

- I saw in logs and in admin panel that order Id is 53 so I've checked `sales_flat_order_addres` and `sales_flat_quote_address` tables. Data in this tables is correct
- I've created observer on `sales_order_save_before` and I've created log of   Quote , Order, shipping address and shipping method - Data is correct

My questions:

- How It's possible that magento doesn't get proper address by order Id from database ( I see that `parent_id` in `sales_flat_order` with Id 53 have proper address, the same with `sales_flat_qoute` with Id related to my order have proper address too)
- Is there any way to repair this issue or I have to change `/core` directory to new one downloaded from magento page ?

Log Files (Pastebin)

[Quote Log](http://pastebin.com/ypK7vmUd)

[Order Log](http://pastebin.com/40WsPYkx)

[Shipping Address Log](http://pastebin.com/LKgSBLwx)

Comment: How much have you modified your Magento installation? If not at all (other than themes) you could try upgrading, however this seems like a strange issue and probably won't be resolved by an upgrade. When you say the addresses etc are completely different, are they addresses from other orders, or ones that you have entered somewhere else (e.g. my account for registered customers)

Comment: The addresses are from other orders. I'have modified Magento only by templates modules and 2 Javascripts in cart page so modifications arent huge. Can you please tell me which table and function Magento uses to Save order and get data after?

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Did you manage to fix it? What was the cause?